# Displaying a part of the JSON returned from a DB in UWP

Tags: c#, json, uwp

I'm working on parsing JSON data in a UWP app and this currently is my working code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        String MyGetRequest = await GetRequest();



        ResultTextBlock.Text = MyGetRequest.ToString() + " - ";

    }
 public static async Task<String> GetRequest()
    {
        Uri geturi = new Uri("url"); //replace your url
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage responseGet = await client.GetAsync(geturi);
        string response = await responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return response;
   }
```

Now all I want to do is display the data that comes back by one of its values, in this case: Username, I don't need to display the rest of the info being retrieved from the database. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where do you parse the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "Newtonsoft.Json" nuget package to your application, in order to parse the json you receive.
In order to parse it to a typed definition. You need to create a class in your application, that has the same properties as your json abject.

```
var json = await responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(json);
```

Then you can return result.Username

Newtonsoft Json also has a function called JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType in the case if you don't want to define your class you can refer to http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137214/discussion-on-answer-by-armin-displaying-a-part-of-the-json-returned-from-a-db-i).